# Fixed order gaussian quadrature for $n$-dimensional integrals using `scipy`

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I wish to integrate a n-variate (bi-variate for simplicity) function using the `scipy.integrate.nquad` method. However, I would also like to use a fixed-order quadrature rule, as in `scipy.integrate.fixed_quad`, however I have not been able to find a way to do this.

Is this a known problem, and are there any clever ways of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. Are you asking if there exists a n-variate version of `fixed_quad`?

Comment: Yes! Your way of putting it was way better, thanks! Say i have a scalar function `f(x)` which accepts a numpy array of shape `(n,)` as input, and returns a scalar. How would I go about integrating this with a fixed quadrature rule?